# Out of bounds exception: 6

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I am trying to create a program that will play the game connect four. When trying to insert a counter it compiles with no problem, but when I try to enter something into the program it displays the message:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception: 6

whilst highlighting the line

> ```
> System.out.print("|" + " " + board[row][col]);
> ```

The full method involved is:

```
public static void playGame() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[][] board = new String[6][7];
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++)
            board[row][col] = " ";
    int column = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
        displayBoard();
        String turn = "R" ;
        System.out.print("Red player enter number 0 - 6: ");
        column = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("|" + " " + board[row][col]);
        board[row][col] = "R";
        displayBoard();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you not using `i` and `j` instead of `row` and `col`? Your code makes no sense atm. Provide a [mcve], please.

Comment: you say i <= 6 well you can't go to board[6][#] and that's why you are getting the arry out of bounds error. use i < board.length

Answer (score 1):

You need to base your i off the board's length and not some magic number

```
//use the i & j's to set your board
for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++)
        board[i][j] = " ";


for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
    displayBoard();
    String turn = "R" ;
    System.out.print("Red player enter number 0 - 6: ");
    column = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("|" + " " + board[i][column]);
    board[i][column] = "R";
    displayBoard();
}
```